# Errors when generating mixed mode Flame Graphs

Tags: performance, centos7, flamegraph

I'm trying to generate some mixed mode flame graphs on a Linux machine (CentOS 7) and running into some issues.

I'm following instructions from this link: https://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/java-performance-analysis-on-linux-with-flame-graphs (starting from slide 47).

when I run the below command to collect perf data:

```
perf record -F 997 -a -g --sleep <time in seconds>; jmaps
```

It seems to generate perf.data with no errors. However, when I try to process the perf.data by running the below command,

```
 perf script --input=perf.data > out.stacks01
```

it shows me below messages:

```
/tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll6943913993058681852.so was updated (is prelink enabled?). Restart the long running apps that use it!
corrupted callchain, skipping
```

Does anyone have any idea what these messages mean?